# App hub & Xbox development membership

Tags: xna, xbox360

I accidentally signed up on app hub as an individual but meant to as a student. Is there anyway of switching this? The same live ID is signed up on dreamspark and verified already.

I tried asking in the app hub forums, but I'm not getting any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft requires that you submit a support ticket in order to get it changed:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/69335.aspx

You can submit a ticket [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/feedback)